# configuring sql server job agent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, jobs

I am trying to configure the SQL Server Job Agent using the following script:

```
USE [msdb]
GO
CREATE USER [mydbuser] FOR LOGIN [mydbuser]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'mydbuser'
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'SQLAgentOperatorRole', N'mydbuser'
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'SQLAgentReaderRole', N'mydbuser'
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'SQLAgentUserRole', N'mydbuser'
go
sp_configure 'show advanced options',1
go
reconfigure with override
go
      sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell',1
go
reconfigure with override
go
sp_configure 'show advanced options',0
go
reconfigure with override


use master
go
GRANT EXECUTE on xp_cmdshell to db_job
go

use master
go
EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'mydomain\db_job', 'password-1'
go

CREATE CREDENTIAL [Job3] WITH IDENTITY = N'mydomain\mydomainuser', SECRET =               N'mydomain\mydomainuser'
GO

USE [msdb]
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_proxy @proxy_name=N'LW_JobRunner',@credential_name=N'Job', 
@enabled=1
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_grant_proxy_to_subsystem @proxy_name=N'LW_JobRunner', @subsystem_id=3
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_grant_login_to_proxy @proxy_name=N'LW_JobRunner',         @login_name=N'mydbuser'
GO

/* Setting up job Category */

DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
SELECT @ReturnCode = 0

EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL',             @name=N'MyJob'
go

USE MASTER
GO

EXEC master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_proxy_account N'SET',
     N'DEV',            -- agent_domain_name
     N'Administrator',  -- agent_username
     N'password'        -- agent_password
```

But the last step on executing the `sp xp_sqlagent_proxy_account`, says

> Could not find the stored proccedure xp_sqlagent_proxy_account.

I'm sure I'm executing it on the `master` db with the `sa` credentials...

And because of this on adding a job I get an error like this

> Could not find the server 'myIpAddress' in sys.servers. Verify that
>   the correct server name was specified . If necessary, execute the
>   stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This error usually happens when non-sysadmin users try to execute xp_cmdshell. You are however stating that you are sure that you are executing in master db with sa credentials.

You might want to try running this:

```
-- Enable non-system administrators to run the job and to execute xp_cmdshell.
EXECUTE msdb..sp_set_sqlagent_properties @sysadmin_only = 0
GO
```

This will allow non-sa users to access xp_cmdshell. If it then works, that would mean that the user account under which your script is running is a non-sa account.

Hope this helps.

Raj

Comment: I am getting the following error   @@sysadmin_only flag is no longer supported by SQLAgent and kept here only for backwards compatibility

Comment: You are right. Since your question did not talk about SQL version, I made a generic suggestion. I just now noticed the SQL 2008 tag. Sorry